# Which visa category do we have to apply to go to Belgium for religious purposes?

Tags: schengen

We will go to Belgium for religious purposes, and need a visa. Which visa category should we apply for? Is there a specific visa class for it and what is the required document checklist? We have already visited multiple times the UK to conduct religious conferences. Can we apply for a multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Comment: Are you recognized as clergy in Belgium?

Comment: we are recoganised clergy in india and have invitation letter from belgium

Answer (score 2):

A multiple entry visa will usually be granted after a number of successful visits on single-entry visa (no overstays or similar incidents). This happens *automatically* when they consider your application. While it is possible to request a multiple-entry visa in the form, this would be unusual to be granted for a first-time visitor.

I'm not aware of special rules for clergy. The visa form has both a "cultural" and "other" check box, one of those would seem to fit.